# how to read the quickfixJ filestore message files

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

seems that the filestore for the quickfixj messages are stored in a unreadable charaters. Whats the best tool to read it?
Also, is there any design that use the filestore as a backup without manually requesting resend some of the earlier messages?
Where could I configure how much message data I want to save in the filestore?

Comment: Anyone had an experience with this?

Comment: Well that is weird. If I'm looking at the filestore directory, I'm seeing clearly readable FIX message log files. The file names are usually formatted as `FIX.<FIX version>-<SenderCompID>-<TargetCompID>.messages.log`. Are you sure you are looking into the correct file?

Comment: Also if you have several questions on a topic, it is best to ask each question in a new Stack Overflow question, rather than asking them all in one such question.